# This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. android.useAndroidX=true is in settings

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I already have this property in my **gradle.properties**:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

FLIPPER_VERSION=0.54.0

org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

But I still get this error after syncing gradle, deleting build, invalidating cache, deleting .gradle. I tried to delete settings file to check if its being read by build daemon and then build, as expected, crashes.

Comment: Where have you placed your `grade.properties`? It must be `android/gradle.properties` .

Comment: Oh, you saved me, thank you! Somehow it was at `android/app`. Everything works fine after moving it.